# Is there a way to access HTTP response headers in pure Java EL?

Tags: java, http-headers, el

Java EL has the implicit `${header}` map, which gives you access to the HTTP **request** headers. Is there any affordance for accessing the HTTP **response** headers?

The only guidance I've found suggested using a scriptlet like the one below, but combining scriptlets and EL is often frowned upon:

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("fooBar", response.getHeader("X-Foo-Bar")); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access a `response` object in EL via `pageContext`

```
${pageContext.response.getHeader('X-Foo-Bar')}
```

See [Implicit Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnaij/index.html) for more information.